# HTTPS with self-signed SSL certificate server and embedding CSS in an HTML file

Tags: html, css

I'm using self-signed SSL certificate for my private HTTPS server. The problem is is cannot load `.css` file embedded by

```
<style type="text/stylesheet" src="/default.css"></style>
```

I think this is related with security something. What should I do to make browser to load my css file?

Comment: What goes wrong? What shows up in the server's log files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your syntax. That's how you include JavaScript, but CSS files are linked to with a `<link>` element or an `@import`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/default.css" />
```